# Why does $dbh->do('VACUUM') fail with Perl's DBD::SQLite?

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, dbi, vacuum

I want to do `VACUUM` at a certain time on a SQLite database under Perl, but it always says

> DBD::SQLite::db do failed: cannot VACUUM from within a transaction

So how do I do this?

```
my %attr = ( RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname='.$file'','',\%attr) 
    or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I am using `AutoCommit => 0`. And the error happens while:

```
$dbh->do('DELETE FROM soap');
$dbh->do('DELETE FROM result');
$dbh->commit; 
$dbh->do('VACUUM');
```

Comment: <pre lang="perl">
my %attr = (
    RaiseError => 0,
    PrintError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 0 );
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname='.$file'','',\%attr) or die $DBI::errstr;
</pre>
I am using AutoCommit => 0 .

And the error happens while:
<pre lang="perl">
$dbh->do('DELETE FROM soap;');
$dbh->do('DELETE FROM result;');
$dbh->commit;
$dbh->do('VACUUM');
</pre>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am assuming you have `AutoCommit => 0` in the connect call because the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:test.db', undef, undef,
    { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}
);

$dbh->do('VACUUM');

$dbh->disconnect;
```

You don't have to give up on transactions to be able to `VACUUM`: You can use the following so that `AutoCommit` is turned on for `VACUUM` and after the `VACUUM` the `AutoCommit` state is reverted back to whatever it was. Add error checking to taste if you do not set `RaiseError`.

```
sub do_vacuum {
    my ($dbh) = @_;
    local $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 1;
    $dbh->do('VACUUM');
    return;
}
```

Call it:

```
do_vacuum($dbh);
```

Comment: So, VACUUM needs AutoCommit=1 to disable transaction.
Thanks.

Comment: +1  Suggest `local $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 1;` and dispensing with the `$ac` variable.

Comment: Why didn't I know you could use `local` on elements of *lexical* arrays & hashes? Perl still has a few surprises for me. :D

Comment: I forget it all the time and have to check `perldoc perlsub`: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29

Answer (score 1):

The DBI has autocommit turned on by default.  Turn it off during the connect:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { AutoCommit => 0 });
```

Comment: Chas. I think you have it reversed. `AutoCommit` needs to be on for `$dbh->do('VACCUM')` to occur outside of a transaction.